# looping through folder and echoing filename

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Can anyone help me with why this doesn't work. Terminal doesn't complain it being run with ./FHTest.sh but it doesn't output anything either. Using the same method in another shell script and I'm able to loop through every file.

```
#!/bin/bash

OrDir="/Volumes/Misc/Downloads"
find "$OrDir" -type f -exec /bin/bash -c \
    'f2=$(basename "$1")
        echo "${f2%.*}"
     ' _ {} \;
```

output from `ls -l`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 xxx  staff         173  6 Oct 14:51 FHTest.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program seems to be working fine here. Some things to check might be to specify -H and/or -L to `find` ( the only two POSIX supported options (-exec is an operand)) which control behavior when encountering symlinks. Also use `printf` instead of `echo` whenever possible. Though `printf` is a bit tricky it pays off in the end as `echo` varies in subtle ways across shells.

```
#!/bin/sh 
OrDir="$(pwd)"
find "$OrDir" -type f -exec /bin/bash -c \
'f2=$(basename "$1")
 f2="${f2%.*}"
 printf "$f2\n"
 ' _ {} \;
```

Comment: Brilliant is working now! Ill remember to avoid echo in future - Thanks